# Bootstrap Modal messes up Carousel CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a carousel with modified css because the default font and color of the captions/icons on the images are impossible to see, so I changed the arrows' style and color as well as the caption position/color.

However, when I activate my modal on the page, it resets all of the css applied to the carousel. Why is this happening?

My CSS:

```
/* CAROUSEL CSS */

.carousel-caption {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
    justify-content: start;
}
.carousel-control-next{
    justify-content: end;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='red' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");

}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='red' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

/* for screens smaller then mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .carousel-caption {
        color: red;
        font-size:12px;
    }
}

/* for screens bigger then mobile */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .carousel-caption {
        color: black;
        font-size:18px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
  <!-- NavBar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Land Power</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
          </li>
          <!-- <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact Us<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
          </li> -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
        <button class="signup btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" linkFile="contact.html" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="contact.html" data-target="#theModal">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Modal -->

  <div class="modal fade" id="theModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Carousel -->
  <div class="container">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner ">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block mw-80 mx-auto img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/arch" alt="First slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption bg-secondary ">
            <h5>First Slide</h5>
            <p>Random Architect Pictures</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block mw-80 mx-auto img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/nature" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption bg-secondary ">
            <h5>Second Slide</h5>
            <p>Random Nature Pictures</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block mw-80 mx-auto img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/animals" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption bg-secondary ">
            <h5>Third Slide</h5>
            <p>Random Animal Pictures</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can try loading in your css after you load in the bootstrap css in the head tag

Comment: to clarify - my modal only renders when users click the `Sign Up` button, so on first load, everything should be there and is working properly. But when a user clicks `Sign Up` and the modal loads new content, this is where my css becomes a mess.
Also my css is already being loaded in the head tag after the bootstrap link