# Bootstrap Modal Closing Behavior

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a button `Sign Up` that loads in content from another file in the form of a Modal. When I click the button for the first time, the script works normally with no errors/warnings. However after the first time, if I dismiss the modal by clicking off of the element, clicking the `Sign Up` button again STILL WORKS, however it now throws a console error, stating `$(...).modal(...).find(...).load(...)` is not a function. In another one of my posts trying to solve this issue, I discovered the `.load()` method wouldn't work because I had the wrong version of jquery sourced in the file. But since then I have fixed that issue and the Modal now works, so I don't understand where this error is coming from.

Secondly, when the modal appears, it darkens the rest of the page (normal behaviour of the modal), if I try to dismiss the modal using the close button in the header, the modal disappears however the rest of my page is left darkened?/left out of focus? and the page becomes un-interactable...

Thirdly, I posted this as a seperate question due to the difference in nature: [Bootstrap Modal messes up Carousel CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69621837/bootstrap-modal-messes-up-carousel-css?noredirect=1#comment123060387_69621837)

How do I fix these issues?

HTML file

```
<!-- NavBar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Land Power</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
          </li>
          <!-- <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact Us<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
          </li> -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
        <button class="signup btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" linkFile="contact.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#theModal">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Modal -->

  <div class="modal fade" id="theModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sign Up</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Modal content load script

```
  <script>
    $('.signup').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.modal').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('linkFile'));
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is likely that you are including bootstrap from two sources. Check your code to make sure you are including bootstrap from only one source. I had a similar issue not too long ago, solved when I realized bootstrap was being automatically included from another CDN.

Here is a jsfiddle containing your code inside a bootstrap template. It works as you have described it to.

https://jsfiddle.net/fatchild/b04r7Ljo/3/

```
It is a good idea to take your code out of context into a tool like JSfiddle in order to isolate the bug. As you can see there is nothing wrong with the code you have supplied.
```

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with JSFiddle, could you explain why/how taking the code out of context into a tool like JSfiddle `isolates` the bug?

Comment: I have tried matching the link sourcing to JSFiddle, and it seems to have only fixed my 2nd issue (where the screen stays dark after dismissing the modal). Problems 1 and 3 still persist

Comment: Isolating an issue is a good skill to have in programming. If you have an issue like "this thing doesn't work", you can then make a guess "I think it is not working because of this". You can then test that hypothesis by removing it from the equation and seeing if it fixes the issue. JSFiddle just allows you to recreate the webpage in a completely different environment, so you can see if the issue is environmental (i.e. on you own system) or not.

Comment: Share the JSFiddle you have created, and we can compare the differences between what is working and what is not :)

Comment: I included the updated HTML file as well as the CSSfile, however the CSS doesn't seem to be taking effect? I'm not sure how to apply the CSS in JSFiddle (line 15), so before you look at the result, you will need to link them. Also testing with the JSFiddle, I am unsure how to load a 2nd HTML file (to fill the contents of the Modal component) as this is what I suspect is the reason for issue 1. But alone in the tool, the console does not seem be showing the error message mentioned in issue 1.

https://jsfiddle.net/7rcm1qw0/9/

Comment: Well this probably tells you that the issue in the code may be the inclusion of the new HTML. Because everything is working without it.